# How to put number on the left and percentage and word 'Off' stack on the right

Tags: html, css

I would like to do a text 20% off but number on the left and percentage and off stack on the right. Can you guy give me an idea? [Image to Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cCH3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this.

```css
.discount-number-wrapper {
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
}

.discount-number-wrapper:before {
  content: '%';
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
}

.discount-number-wrapper:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount-number-wrapper">
  20
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using float: left we can do it.Hope this helps.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="float:left">
     <div style="font-size:40px;">20</div>
     
  </div>
  <div style="float:left">
  <div >%</div>
   <div >Off</div>
  </div>
</div>
```